# find the max. and min from a Point3DCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I notice that Point3DCollection has Max() and Min(). However, there is no example to show how they are used.

suppose I have a collection like this:

```
Point3DCollection list = new Point3DCollection();
            list.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, 8));
            list.Add(new Point3D(4, 5, 4));
            list.Add(new Point3D(2, 8, 9));
```

What would Max() and Min() supposed to return for a Point3DCollection? any code examples to show the use of these two methods?

This code:  (outputText is a text box)

```
outputText.Text = list.Max().ToString();
```

Will only generate error instead of any meaningful output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
outputText.Text = list.Max(p=>p.X * p.X + p.Y*p.Y + p.Z * p.Z).ToString();
```

`Max` is a linq extension function (not Point3DCollections) and operates on comparable items, Point3D is not comparable, so u can use something like above to do comparision.

Answer (score 1):

it probably returns the point with the smallest and largest length. This is sqrt( p1.x*p1.x + p1.y*p1.y + p1.z*p1.z)